# Handling Angular errors on button click

Tags: angular, error-handling, onclick

I have an angular table in the front end with a delete button in it that onClick will delete the row, connected to ColdFusion backend.

If in a scenario the table page loads as usual, but right before the user clicks the delete button, the api goes down

How can I throw an error so it doesn't continue then on to the next page?

Comment: we need more details. is this table using an observable, an http call, etc

Answer (score 0):

Return an error code value from your `delete()` function. Let's say `0` if everything went ok and `1` *or any number* if something went wrong.

You can also add a [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) after which you consider that there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going show an example here how you can display an error to the user instead of doing what you are supposed to do, on a button click, which is connected to http call.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqm9h7?file=app/app.component.ts)

**component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  logs: string[] = [];

  errorFetch: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  onClick(event) {
    this.http.get("https://weather.cit.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_7days_simple&latitude=" + "&longitude=" + "&app_id=" + "&app_code=" + "jsonpCallback")
        .subscribe(result => {
            // if everything goes well do what you want here
            console.log("success getting weather results");
          },
          (err) => {
            //if the back end is down
            //error getting data
            //set a flag to show an error
            this.errorFetch = true;

            //here click on the button click me, to see the result
            //because the weather api is not responding you get to this block
            //of code
          },
          () => {
            //subscribe has finished
          }         
        );
  }
}
```

**template:**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<button (click)="onClick($event)">click me</button>

<div *ngIf="errorFetch" style="color:red;"> error getting weather data</div>
```

just click on the button `click me` and since there is an error getting the data, you can do something else in this case rather the deleting, in the appropriate block of code.